# How do I install UWP tools installer for visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I saw questions that answered as to where I could install 
UWP tools installer (Universe Windows Platform)

But the link no longer works.

I already installed Community Edition of the Visual Studio (2015), and I have SDK for Windows 10 already on my computer.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to get the UWP Tools Installer

Comment: Add/remove programs -> select the VS 2015 product -> Modify/Change -> Modify -> select "Universal Windows App Development Tools" | "Tools (1.4.1) and Windows SDK (0.0.14393)"

Comment: i think its working.  if you post it as an answer, rather than a comment, you can have the credit for answering it.  it is installing right now.  i think it will work....

Comment: If you want to target newer W10 than 14393 you'll have to use VS 2017. 14393 is more than a year old and there were two major updates since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Add/Remove programs* and select the Microsoft Visual Studio product. Click Modify or Change.

When the VS 2015 setup comes up, select *Modify*

Look under "Universal Windows App Development Tools"

Click the checkbox next to "Tools (1.4.1) and Windows SDK (0.0.14393)" and click OK.

Comment: I had done the same thing but still I'm unable to get `UWP` under `Windows 10` in `VS 2015`. #help :-(